# Add a bottom border to a div

Tags: css

I am trying to add a bottom border to a div

```
.divLast
{
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px;  
   padding: 0px 2px 2px 3px;    
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom-width:2px;
   border-bottom-color:White;
   width: 100%;
}
```

However the bottom border does not appear white. Any idea?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to specify the [border-bottom-style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530726%28VS.85%29.aspx) also to the div

and your code becomes

```
.divLast 
{
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px;  
   padding: 0px 2px 2px 3px;    
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom-width:2px;
   border-bottom-color:White;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   width: 100%;
}
```

or you can use a shorthand for the [border-bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530724%28VS.85%29.aspx) like below

```
<style>
.divLast 
{
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px;  
   padding: 0px 2px 2px 3px;    
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom: 2px white solid;
   width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class='divLast'>
   test element with white border bottom
</div>
```

This works fine for me

Answer (score 8):

It's because you need to state what the border style is. Without this the border wont show:

```
border-bottom-style:solid;
```

You could also combine your declerations into one like so:

```
border-bottom:2px solid White;
```